# iCloud - Core data sync issue

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, icloud

I get this one error at a critical stage in the app.
The scenario is that the MainView gets the listings of entities "Category" in the main view using a predicate "User == %@", currentUser.

This page is synced well across the devices via icloud.

There is a User<----->Category <---->>Field<--------->>Entry (timestamp, value). <<------------>User
The only difference in this is that Entries can belong to different Users. hence the last relationship.

WHEN I do add an "Entry" entity, its created fine locally, but when the logs arrive in the receiving device (via iCloud)... i get this:

```
2012-02-21 06:36:55.573 APPCloud[2403:4923] -[_PFUbiquityRecordsImporter operation:failedWithError:](839): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Import operation ecountered an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134060.)" UserInfo=0x79ce410 {exception=Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'forUser' between objects in different contexts (source = <Entry: 0x855eac0> (entity: Entry; id: 0x855e6b0 <x-coredata:///Entry/tDF69E4F8-35DE-4DC1-8077-F5A563FE0DCC1041> ; data: {    comment = nil;
    forField = nil;
    forUser = nil;
    period = 0;
    timeStamp = nil;
    value = 0;
}) , destination = <User: 0x288820> (entity: User; id: 0x232a10 <x-coredata://43C097FE-4A91-42A9-B8EC-CF32D65F7328/User/p1> ; data: {
    birthday = "1999-02-20 21:00:00 +0000";
    entries =     (
        "0x79aa590 <x-coredata:///Entry/tDF69E4F8-35DE-4DC1-8077-F5A563FE0DCC16>",
        "0x2071d0 <x-coredata://43C097FE-4A91-42A9-B8EC-CF32D65F7328/Entry/p1>",
        "0x206bf0 <x-coredata://43C097FE-4A91-42A9-B8EC-CF32D65F7328/Entry/p2>"
    );
    firstName = Samuel;
    fullName = nil;
    height = 0;
    images =     (
    );
    lastName = User;
    male = 1;
    trackers =     (
        "0x797bb60 <x-coredata://43C097FE-4A91-42A9-B8EC-CF32D65F7328/Tracker/p1>"
    );
    uuid = "07110878-F6D3-482D-BC0E-3CE8B4A581E4HGMG";
    years = 0;
}))} while trying to import the log file at the URL: <PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x79ca620>
```

I use the same context, i dont know whats going on here... and when these logs arrive, none of the other stuf works..

Please point me to the right direction!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you adding this to a nil or a property context? Try not using the local property context

Comment: yea, apparently the context i was adding on was not initialized correctly. how lame of me!